# Mule http request giving 404 mapped as failure

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I am trying to pass the multiple URI params in the http request as follows:

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"
    connectionIdleTimeout="40000" />
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" protocol="HTTPS" host="" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" connectionIdleTimeout="300000" responseTimeout="50000">
    <http:basic-authentication username="user" password="123"/>
</http:request-config>    
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/paypal" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-variable variableName="config" value="#[{'p1':'3054', 'p2':'child/Lines'}]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="/resources/shipment/{p1}/{p2}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:uri-params expression="#[flowVars.config]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

But this is giving me error as below:

**Response code 404 mapped as failure.**

```
ERROR 2019-01-04 18:46:34,526 
[[paypaltest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] 
org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 


********************************************************************************
Message               : Response code 404 mapped as failure.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@b473ec2
Element               : /testFlow/processors/1 @ test:test.xml:29 (HTTP)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="/resources/shipments/{p1}/{p2}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
                        <http:request-builder>
                        <http:uri-params expression="#[flowVars.config]"></http:uri-params>
                        </http:request-builder>
                        </http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 404 mapped as failure.
```

Please let me know if any help can be provide!

Answer (score 0):

It means that the url doesn't exist. Try to hit the url directly in postman before implementing in Mule. Since you wiped out the host="", I'll pretend it's example.com. My guess is that it's having an issue with p2. If you'd like to send the actual string, you'll need to URL encode the "/", which is `%2F`

So to test hit https://www.example.com/resources/shipments/3054/child%2FLines, with the Basic Auth for Authorization.

Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/apps

Comment: thanks..your guess is right as its working with one parameter i.e. `p1` but as soon as i am implementing `p2` its not working.. I tried your solution but its giving me same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue i faced was unique to me, i tried this REST api call from SOAPUI and there it gave me the same error i.e. `404 not found` so i compared it with POSTMAN request and found that `Authorization` header was the missing piece for this. 
After adding this to `http header` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-authentication

here are two solutions :
1. Add preemptive="true" in basic authentication configuration
The pre-emptive option passes the user name and password without waiting for a prompt from the server.

2. Add Authorization in the http:header value ="Basic dXNlcjoxMjM="